# How do I plug a live data service (REST APIs) running on a different port to my app built with yeoman(angular)?

Tags: angularjs, nginx, tornado, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am new to web development and this question might seem very dumb. But I need help desperately. 
We are bootstrapping a start-up and are using angular, tornado and postgres. I created a basic app using yeoman and the angular generator. I am running the grunt connect on port 9000 to avoid clashing with my other work-related projects.
    The major problem I am facing is that the tornado backend is running on the port 8889. And my webserver is running on 9000. Trying to make a call to the API is throwing a cross-domain blocked error. So I configured nginx to proxy the API calls made to 9000 to the port 8889. This works fine from the rest client. But the webserver is now gone and I get only the proxied API response when I launch the app. 
 Been breaking my head to figure what I need to do. Can someone guide my in how to configure my nginx so that my UI is served properly and I can make the API calls to the port 8889?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out a simple work around for this. [Here](http://www.hierax.org/2014/01/grunt-proxy-setup-for-yeoman.html) is what I used to proxy my API calls to the required port. Hope it helps anyone else who might be in a similar situation.